# Plotly - Remove axis ticks and numbers but keep label

Tags: python, plotly, axis, axis-labels

In this MWE, I have a plot with ticks and labels.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=[2.3], y=[5.3], mode='markers'))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,10], constrain="domain",title_text="Some x label",title_font={"size":22,"color":"black"}, showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x",scaleratio = 1, range=[0,10], title_text="Some y label",title_font={"size":22,"color":"black"}, showgrid=False)
fig.show()
```

[image: With ticks]

If I remove the grid and the ticks, the x label becomes the plot title and the y label stays far away from the plot. How can I just remove the grid and numbers while keeping the axis labels where they are (or even getting them a bit closer to the axis lines as there are no numbers now)?

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=[2.3], y=[5.3], mode='markers'))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,10], constrain="domain",showgrid=False,showticklabels=False,rangemode="nonnegative",
                 title_text="Some x label",title_font={"size":22,"color":"black"})
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x",scaleratio = 1, range=[0,10], showgrid=False,showticklabels=False,rangemode="nonnegative",
                 title_text="Some y label",title_font={"size":22,"color":"black"})
fig.show()
```

[image: Without ticks]

Comment: What version of plotly are you on? I just tried your example with version `5.3.1` and for it looks OK: https://i.imgur.com/eHAqIX8.png

Comment: I ran the second snippet in a Jupyter notebook and it did ouput the desired result, *i.e.* labels stay where they are. Which version of plotly are you using?

Comment: For the record, I am using `5.6.0`.

Comment: I have confirmed the same event with the latest version (5.13.0). Please try the following code as a minimum workaround. The key is to display the scale and set the font color to white.  `fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False,showticklabels=True,color='white',title_text="Some x label",title_font={"size":22,"color":"black"});fig.update_layout(autosize=False, height=450, width=450)` If you don't get an answer, I suggest you ask the plolty [community](https://community.plotly.com/).

Comment: I am using plotly 5.12.0. 
The y axis label seems to be quite affected by the layout height and size. Is this normal??

Comment: In plotly, if you limit the axes as default, the graph and graph title will be far apart, as pointed out, so you need to set the graph size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem only found in recent version of plotly (5.12). For the time being, best solution is downgrade to plotly==5.6.0. `pip install plotly==5.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

I do the following for my own plots: by adjusting the various margin parameters (t - top, b - bottom, l - left, and r - right) till I get the look I wanted.

```
something.update_layout(
width=800,
height=400,
font_family="Times",
font_size=10,
margin_t=50,
margin_b=100,
margin_l=280,
margin_r=150,
margin_pad=5)
```

Hope this helps.