# Using plotly, undo move of axis title when tick labels are not shown

Tags: plotly

Executing the below code using `plotly=5.16.1`

```python
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title="hello world"))
fig.show()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title="hello world", showticklabels=False))
fig.show()
```

results in [image]
and [image]

Is this a bug or a feature?
How to only remove the tick labels, but not move the axis title from bottom to top?

Comment: This event may not yet be resolved. Please refer to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350817/plotly-remove-axis-ticks-and-numbers-but-keep-label).